# Apache Spark RDD substitution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to solve a problem such that I've got a dataset like this:

```
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 7)
(1, 2)   <-
(2, 7)   <-
(6, 6)    
(3, 7)   <-
(7, 4)   <-
...
```

Since  `(1 -> 2)` and `(2 -> 7)`, I would like to replace the set `(2, 7)` as `(1, 7)`
similarly, `(3 -> 7)` and `(7 -> 4)` also replace `(7,4)` as `(3, 4)`

Hence, my dataset becomes

```
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 7)
(1, 2)  
(1, 7)  
(6, 6)    
(3, 7)
(3, 4)
...
```

Any idea how to solve or tackle this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can be clear with ur input value ? its bit confusing. is ur input is RDD[String] ? if no  pls share your RDD format

Comment: Your problem statement isn't very clear. You say (2, 7), (1,7) -> (1,7). But why doesn't (1, 7), (7,4) ->< 1, 4)? In other words, you have lots of potential matches. How do you determine which to choose?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul you're right (1,7), (7,4) will also imply (1, 4) basically, if the value of the map of a previous row equals the key of the map of the current row, then we can replace this as (previous row value, current value)

Comment: Ah. Row-by-row isn't great for Spark. Dataframes + windows, probably. Actually, even windows functions might not do it. WHat happens with (1, 2),(2,3), (3,4)? When the first two get replaced with (1,3) is that it, or do you start the matching again and do (1,3), (3,4) -> (1,4)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul yeah, need to start the matching again

Comment: OK. so we collapse chains until we don't get a match. So this means for any entry, we could need to look ahead an arbitary number of entries, including off one partition into another.  This isn't a good fit for Spark, it seems to me.

Comment: BTW, this is a graph problem. "Transitive Closure" comes to mind. Probably GraphX would be a better option.

Comment: BTW2, you don't seem to accept answers to your questions. That's not cool in SO.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I've been able to use graph to solve the problem but open to try another different approach

Comment: @maasg thanks for the comment, I do accept answers - fyi

Comment: @maasg is right. Please review your answered question and accept what needs to be accepted otherwise comment on why the provided solution didn't work for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem looks like a transitive closure of a graph, represented in the form of a distributed list of edges.

One of the key features of Spark, when compared to older Hadoop MR is that Spark supports interactive algorithms. To solve a graph traversal problem like this, we exploit that capability in a recursive function:

```
def closure(rdd:RDD[(Int, Int)]):RDD[(Int,Int)] = {
  val transitiveValues = rdd.map(_.swap).join(rdd).filter{case (_,(x,y)) => x != y}
  if (transitiveValues.isEmpty) {
    rdd
  } else {
    val usedTransitions = transitiveValues.flatMap{case (a,(x,y)) => Seq((x,a),(a,y))}
    val newTransitions = transitiveValues.map{case (a,(x,y)) => (x,y)}
    closure(rdd.subtract(usedTransitions).union(newTransitions)).distinct
  }
}
```

This does not exactly results in the output expected above, because there's no notion of precedence (implicit ordering), so `closure((1, 2),(2, 7)) = (1,7)` and not in `(1, 2), (1, 7)` as expected above. Ordering can be added at the cost of extra complexity. Also, it does not support cyclic graphs (with loops).

This algorithm should serve only as starting point to be tuned to the specific internal requirements.

Comment: This is a clean answer ! I like the comparison with the Hadoop MR approach