# Combining/joining rows of IDs in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

Given a file filled with rows of IDs e.g.

```
i1, i2, i5
i3, i4
i2, i6, i7
i4, i8
i9, i3
```

How would you join them by linking the same IDs? So for the example above, row 1 is linked to row 3 via i2 and row 2 is linked to row 4 and 5 via i4 and i3 respectively. This will give you the following (duplicates removed)

```
i1, i2, i5, i6, i7
i3, i4, i8, i9
```

I could do it by looping through the rows, but was wondering how you would go about it in a functional manner?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240409/apache-spark-rdd-substitution/40256149#40256149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Apache Spark you could use the built in GraphX Component to do the work for you.

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

def cross[Y](xs: Traversable[Y], ys: Traversable[Y]) = for { x <- xs; y <- ys } yield (x, y)

val data = sc.parallelize(List(
    "1\t5\t3", 
    "3\t9\t30",
    "7\t10\t12",
    "10\t7\t13"
))

val prep = data.map(x => x.split("\t").map(_.toLong).toList)

val vertex = prep
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .map(x => x -> s"ID=$x")

val edges = prep
  .map(x => cross(x, x))
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .map(x => new Edge(x._1, x._2, "likes"))

val graph = Graph(vertex, edges)
val linked = graph
  .connectedComponents
  .vertices
  .map(_.swap)
  .groupByKey

linked.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Will Print out the following result:

```
(1,CompactBuffer(30, 3, 9, 1, 5))
(7,CompactBuffer(7, 10, 12, 13))
```

Cross simply creates a cross product of two lists so we can create the edges between all the vertices.

The connectedComponents function will traverse through the graph and find all the vertices which share a edge and create a new graph where each vertex is a tuple of a Vertex Id -> "Primary" Vertex ID.

So:

```
graph.connectedComponents.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)
```

Would print out

```
(30,1)
(1,1)
(3,1)
(5,1)
(7,7)
(9,1)
(10,7)
(12,7)
(13,7)
```

As you can see 1 and 7 have been chosen as the "Primary Vertex" and linked to all the connected Vertices in the first graph. So a simple swap and group will combine together all the connected ids.

Answer (score 1):

Code which works with Spark 2.0+

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate;
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  List(
    "i1, i2, i5",
    "i3, i4",
    "i2, i6, i7",
    "i4, i8")
)

//Group lines with tokens count (determing by the last occurence of comma)
val rddGroupByTokensCount = df.map(row => (row.lastIndexOf(','), row.split(", ")))
  .groupBy(_._1)

//Now gather all the token to single place with flatMap and drop duplicates
val rddUniqueTokens = rddGroupByTokensCount.map(_._2.flatMap(_._2).toSet)

//print grouped unique tokens by the count in each line
rddUniqueTokens.collect().map(println)
```

**Output:**

```
Set(i5, i1, i7, i2, i6)
Set(i3, i4, i8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `O(n * n)` solution which loops through all of the rows  we can use a solution which is `O(n * k)` where *k* is your number of IDs. Like so:

```
val input = ...//I will assume your input is an RDD[List]

val idArray = Array(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id6)//Array containing all IDs
val result = sc.parallelize(idArray, k).map(x => (x, x))  
input = input.map(x => (x(0), if(x.length > 0) x.slice(1, x.length) else null))

//If you can afford to persist it would help greatly:
result.persist
input.persist

//We can make this loop smaller if k is large and your lists are small
//by setting the upper bound of the range to the length of the longest list.
//I'll leave this decision up to you.
for (i <- 0 to k){ 
    result = result.cogroup(input)
    input = input.map((t: (x, y)) => (y(0), if(y.length > 0) y.slice(1, y.length) else null))
}
result.map((t: (x, y)) => y.distinct)//we want distinct lists in output

result.unpersist
input.unpersist
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably sub-optimal but I figured it would be worth posting regardless. It assumes that your input file is small enough to be persisted into memory (because this is all vanilla Scala).

I decided to solve this by treating the given ids as as adjacencies in a graph and then by using a BFS to list all of the connected components.

```
/* Input, can be read from file easily by splitting on ", " */
val lines = List(List("i1", "i2", "i5"),
    List("i3", "i4"),
    List("i2", "i6", "i7"),
    List("i4", "i8"),
    List("i9", "i3"))

/* finds all sequential pairs */
val pairs = lines.flatMap(x => x.dropRight(1).zip(x.drop(1)))

/* create an empty adjacency map: id -> (Set of adjacent vertices) */
val defMap = Map[String, Set[String]]().withDefaultValue(Set[String]())

/* populate the default map with the actual (symmetric) adjacencies */
val adjMap = pairs.foldLeft{defMap}(
    (acc, x) => acc + (x._1 -> (acc(x._1) + x._2)) + (x._2 -> (acc(x._2) + x._1)))

/* BFS algo on map representation of graph */
def mapBFS(adjMap: Map[String, Set[String]]): List[List[String]] =
{
    val v = adjMap.keys
    var globalVisits = List[String]()
    def BFS_r(elems: List[String], visited: List[List[String]]): List[String] =
    {
        val newNeighbors = elems.flatMap(adjMap(_)).filterNot(visited.flatten.contains).distinct
        if (newNeighbors.isEmpty)
            visited.flatten
        else
            BFS_r(newNeighbors, newNeighbors :: visited)
    }
    v.flatMap(x =>{
        if (globalVisits.contains(x))
            None
        else
        {
            val vi: List[String] = BFS_r(List(x), List(List(x)))
            globalVisits = globalVisits ++ vi
            Some(vi)
        }
    }).toList
}
mapBFS(adjMap).foreach{println}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
List(i7, i1, i6, i2, i5)
List(i8, i4, i3, i9)
```

Comment: I have posted this solution on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147446/print-connected-components-scala) if you have some thoughts on how to improve.